# copyng values from one column to another sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list like this:

```
| slope | lower_limit | upper_limit | limit |
|-------|-------------|-------------|-------|
|  -0.5 |          23 |          25 |     0 |
|   0.6 |          23 |          25 |     0 |
|   0.7 |          23 |          25 |     0 |
```

I want to update values of the limit column from the lower limit and upper limit columns, depending of the sign of the slope column. I would like the resulting table to look like this:

```
| slope | lower_limit | upper_limit | limit |
|-------|-------------|-------------|-------|
|  -0.5 |          23 |          25 |    23 |
|   0.6 |          23 |          25 |    25 |
|   0.7 |          23 |          25 |    25 |
```

I am currently using an if, but it changes the value of the whole column, resulting in all values in the limit column being 25

Comment: What do you mean `depending of the sign of the slope` ? depending on what logic?

Comment: if the slope is negative i need the lower_limit and if the slope is positive i need the upper_limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to use `CASE WHEN` in update.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   slope FLOAT, 
  lower_limit INT, 
  upper_limit  INT,
  limit INT
);

INSERT INTO T  VALUES (-0.5,23,25,0);
INSERT INTO T  VALUES (0.6,23,25,0); 
INSERT INTO T  VALUES (0.7,23,25,0);


UPDATE T
SET limit = CASE WHEN slope > 0 THEN upper_limit 
                    ELSE lower_limit  END
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea8a3/1/0)**:

```
| slope | lower_limit | upper_limit | limit |
|-------|-------------|-------------|-------|
|  -0.5 |          23 |          25 |    23 |
|   0.6 |          23 |          25 |    25 |
|   0.7 |          23 |          25 |    25 |
```